# How can I implement a multiple choice for fields in Wagtail?

Tags: wagtail

How can I implement a multiple choice for fields in Wagtail? For example, I would like the user to be able to select `h2`, `h3`, or `h4` for a field in the Wagtail editorial dashboard. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a field with [a `choices` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#choices):

```
HEADING_SIZE_CHOICES = [
    ('h2', 'h2'),
    ('h3', 'h3'),
    ('h4', 'h4'),
]

class MyPage(Page):
    heading_size = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=HEADING_SIZE_CHOICES)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('heading_size')
    ]
```

This will then display in the page editor as a select dropdown, and can be used like any other field:

```
<{{ page.heading_size }}>{{ page.title }}</{{ page.heading_size }}>
```